# How to pass options with render partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to pass options with render partials? Or maybe I need to set some locals and check against them? I'm confused. I'm looking for something like this:

**views/articles/_post.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/info" %>
<%#= SILLY GUESS: render partial: "shared/info", locals: { from_articles: true } %>
```

**views/stories/_post.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/info" %>
<%#= SILLY GUESS: render partial: "shared/info", locals: { from_stories: true } %>
```

How do I do something like this?

**views/shared/_info.html.erb**

```
<% if called from views/articles/_post.html.erb %>
  <p>Foo</p>
<% elsif called from views/stories/_post.html.erb %>
  <p>Bar</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params hash will always contain the `:controller` and `:action` keys, but you should use the methods `controller_name` and `action_name` instead to access these values. You have two alternatives but the second is a better practice.

```
<% if params[:controller] == articles %>
  <p>Foo</p>
<% elsif params[:controller] == stories %>
  <p>Bar</p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if controller_name == articles %>
  <p>Foo</p>
<% elsif controller_name == stories %>
  <p>Bar</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I like the sound of that!!

Comment: Yep. Would have accepted sooner but SO has a 5 min mandatory time limit. Thanks!!