# using two controllers in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm making contact form on simple site using ruby on rails. Problem is following. I have main controller `StaticPages` that makes plain html with header and footer. Now i made controller `Contacts` that displays view with simple contact form on separate url. When i try to add this form to my contact page from `StaticPages` it doesn't work. i don't know how to tell rails that this form should find method not from `StaticPages` controller but from `Contacts` controller.

Here is my code:

Contacts controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thanks!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Error!'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

StaticPages controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def about_us
  end

  def contact_us
  end

end
```

and here is the form i need to work on StaticPage contact_us

```
<div align="center">
  <h3>Send us message</h3>

  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    <div class= "hidden">
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      </br>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Send', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I guess I need to tell rails that this form should be looking for particular controller, but I don't know how.

Please help.

Comment: i just answered a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884138/how-to-pass-options-with-render-partials/29884200#29884200

Comment: i didn't get the point. maybe you could tell me more how it relates to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you're looking for but it should work the way you want, you should have a `contacts_helper.rb`, that should look like this

```
module ContactsHelper
  def contact_us
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
end
```

In your partial you'll want

```
<%= simple_form_for contact_us, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

And finally you need to include your helper, in `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  ...
  include ContactsHelper
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy option would be to have the `StaticPages` `contact_us` action `redirect_to new_contact_url` (assuming that form lives at `app/views/contacts/new.html.erb`)

Alternatively, you could put the form in `app/views/shared/_new_contact.html.erb`, then put in `@contact = Contact.new` in your `contact_us` action, and have the `contact_us` template `render partial: "shared/new_contact", locals: { :contact => @contact }`.

Comment: but wouldn't i lose all my html body from `contact_us` page and end up with raw form? i would need to have working form inside all my `contact_us` so page would display everything.

Comment: edited my answer to offer another approach that might solve your problem

Comment: just edited code. it stills throw out this error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` what do you think?

Comment: The `contact_us` action on the `StaticPagesController` has `@contact = Contact.new` on it? That would seem to assure `@contact` is not nil ...

Comment: yes i wrote it. still the same problem. it makes no sense right? it works if i use old configuration with separate url such as `/contacts` but now with `/contact_us`

Comment: Not a great practice, but what happens if you change the view to say `simple_form_for Contact.new` ... ? Really curious as to why `@contact` is coming up nil.

Comment: omg it worked. Now i only need to figure out how to make it with `@contact` Any ideas?

Comment: edited the answer again - maybe explicitly passing the `@contact` you initialized in the `contact_us` action via the `locals` option in the render statement?

Comment: Did that work? I think the `locals` statement should let you access `@contact` as `contact` (e.g. `simple_form_for contact`) without initializing any objects in your views ...

Comment: nothing worked! even my tests went crazy. I couldn't even run server anymore. I will start over with new git branch. Maybe you know some good tutorial for Contact Form in rails?